# Using stdlib's qsort() to sort an array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, segmentation-fault, qsort

Some preface:  I'm a computer engineering student taking a first class in C after 3 semesters of Java (up to data structures).  This question is in relation to a homework assignment, but a few steps removed from solving it for me.

I have an input file that I read into memory such that it is stored in char[9][500].  I read in at most 500 strings of maximum length 8.  I am attempting to sort this array using stdlib's built in qsort() function, and am having some memory errors.

Important snippets of code:

```
char data[4][500][60];
char debug[500][9];
size_t count = 0;

/* initialize file, open for reading */
FILE* pUserlog;
pUserlog = fopen("userlog","r");

while(!feof(pUserlog))
{
    fscanf(pUserlog, "%9s %8s %16s",debug[count], data[1][count], data[2][count]);
    fgets(data[3][count], 60, pUserlog);
    count++;
}
```

This section reads the data into the arrays.  The array of interest in this part is "debug".  This is the array specified above.  Here is my comparison function for qsort:

```
int compare(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    const char **ia = (const char **)a;
    const char **ib = (const char **)b;
    puts("I'm in compare!");
    return strncmp(*ia, *ib,8);
}
```

This is my attempt to call qsort:

```
size_t debug_len = sizeof(debug)/sizeof(char*);
printf("debug len: %d, count: %d, sizeof(char*): %d\n",debug_len,count,sizeof(char*));
qsort(debug,count, sizeof(char *), compare);
```

I attempted substituting debug_len in my call where count is, but I am still segfaulting.  Here is the output:

```
$ ./test
debug len: 1125, count: 453, sizeof(char*): 4
I'm in compare!
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Thank you!

Comment: while( !feof() ) is wrong.  feof will return false, the loop will be entered, the scanf will fail to read data, debug[ count ] will contain bogus data, and then feof will return true.  You can fix this case by doing count-- after the loop, but in general you should simply never do while( !feof())

Comment: Where does it segfault?  It is a good exercise to examine the core dump to determine where the segfault happens, as that usually tells you what the problem is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compare function will receive pointers to the elements that are being compared.  You are effectively trying to compare characters using `strncmp()`.  Since you have pointers to each of the strings, cast it to a `char *` and compare.

```
int compare(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    const char *ia = (const char *)a;
    const char *ib = (const char *)b;
    puts("I'm in compare!");
    return strncmp(ia, ib, 9);
}
```

Remember also, it's an array of arrays, not an array of pointers.  So the size of an element should be the size of the array, `9` and not of the pointer, `4`.  At this point, it would be easier to just use `sizeof debug[0]` since it is a two-dimensional array.  If you don't do this with the right sizes, `qsort()` will just destroy your array.

```
size_t elemsize = sizeof debug[0];      /*   9 - size of each element */
size_t count = sizeof(debug)/elemsize;  /* 500 - number of elements in array */
qsort(debug, count, elemsize, compare);
```

Answer (score 4):

What happens here is: you've got 500 strings. Now you pass all 500 to qsort, and it in turn passes each one as first and second argument to your compare function. It's a bit like writing this:

```
compare(debug[0], debug[1])
```

The C compiler passes the addresses, not the actual values of course. But now you interpret the pointer-to-void as pointer-to-pointer-to-char. Your code now does a dereference when calling `strncmp`, but that makes the *value* (the first 4 bytes) be treated as a pointer in `strncmp`. But `strncmp` will now in turn try to dereference the garbage "pointer" (which consists of part of one of your strings) and that makes *bang*.

To fix this, use `char *` instead of `char **`:

```
int compare(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    puts("I'm in compare!");
    return strncmp((const char *)a, (const char *)b, 8);
}
```