# Where does the pointer "char **strData" point to?

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-to-pointer

From the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28537858/9126153) there is the pointer `char **strData = NULL;` in line 12. I'm new to C and pointers. I get, that it is a pointer, which points to *another* pointer. I just don't see the other pointer.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: `strData[noOfLines] = (char*)calloc(MAX_LEN,sizeof(char));`? It is unclear from your question what exactly is confusing you about that code. Can you try to be a little more specific?

Comment: It is a pointer that *might potentially point to* another pointer.  When setting a pointer to NULL it means it is not actually pointing anywhere yet. Later on in the code the pointer will be pointed somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strData = (char**)realloc(strData, sizeof(char**)*(noOfLines+1));` is in the while loop, so `strData` points to a memory block, which can hold pointer. `sizeof(char**)` should be `sizeof(char*)`.

It is followed by `strData[noOfLines] = (char*)calloc(MAX_LEN,sizeof(char));`, which is the pointer you asked for.

So `strData` points to a block of pointers, `strData[i]` points to a block of `char`s.

Comment: `sizeof *strData` is even better, that stops repeating the type and lets the compiler figure it out from the target pointer variable instead.

Comment: Or better yet, self-documenting code: `strData = realloc( strData, sizeof(char*[noOfLines+1]) );`.

Comment: @unwind I thought about that and also about removing the cast, but then I decided to give the shortest possible answer to not spread more confusion.