# Qsort not sorting char * array

Tags: c, arrays, char, qsort

I've got a problem, which is, qsort sometimes sorts stuff, sometimes it doesn't. Here's my code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


static int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return strcmp (*(const char **) a, *(const char **) b);
}

int main (){
  int ile = 0;
  scanf("%d", &ile);
  const char * slowa[ile];
  for(int j = 0; j <= ile; j++){
    char string[30];
    gets(string); 
    char * toAdd = strdup(string);
    slowa[j] = toAdd;
  }
  qsort (slowa, ile, sizeof (const char *), compare);

  for (int i = 0; i <= ile; i++) {
      printf ("%s\n",slowa[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It works well with example { ccc,bbb,aaa } but does not work for the example { afdg ,sspade , trekk, bbre, lol}

Comment: You iterate once too many, should be `j < ile;` and `i < ile;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5370753/1212012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `scanf` has left a newline in the input buffer, which is read by the first `gets`.

The two loops iterate once too many, indexing the array beyond its bounds. I guess you did that to get the correct number of apparent inputs.

So clear the input before the first loop, perhaps with a dummy string read, and correct the loop control.

Also please note that `gets()` is now obsolete.

Comment: i've add     fflush(stdin) and corrected the loop control, works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: @Karol.T please note that `fflush(stdin)` is non-standard behaviour.